# Why does bash fork bomb need pipe?

Tags: bash, shell, fork

For the classical bash fork bomb:

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

I modify it as following:

```
:(){ :& };:
```

Execute and it exits immediately. Per my understanding, `:` function should recursively create child process in background. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: This might help: [How does this bash fork bomb work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/991142/3776858)

Comment: *sarnold*'s answer to [How does this other version of the bash fork bomb work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8394535/6136214) is also good, it has some pseudo process tree pictures of both classes of forkbomb that may help explain what the difference is between having the pipe and not having it.

Answer (score 0):

Because there's always only one recursion path of the function `:()`

The original fork bomb invokes two more instances simultaneously every invocation, using up system resources quickly. However your modified version only invokes itself once, making a simple recursion. It'll probably end up overflowing the stack and doing no more harm.

Comment: `:() { :; }` would overflow the call stack, not the one that forks a background processes.

Comment: Your first sentence ("only one running instance of `:`") contradicts your last.

Comment: @chepner It halts after invoking another instance. Can you suggest a better wording?

Comment: Just drop the last sentence.

Comment: @chepner Drop "*It'll probably end up overflowing the stack and doing no more harm*"?

Comment: @chepner, I'm trying to reproduce the idea that a backgrounded function call from within a function consumes no stack frame. My current test case is `count=0; recurTest() { if (( ++count < 10 )); then echo "$count ${#FUNCNAME[@]}"; recurTest & fi; }; recurTest`, but as you can see, the depth of the `FUNCNAME` array increases with each recursion level. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?